# Is it true that moksha state is of infinite time?

Tags: moksha, atma

Unlike most other religions hinduism says that hell and heaven are temporary and moksha is the ultimate state.

My doubt is if someone reach moksha state, is it of infinite time?

During hell or heaven the soul has consciousness and can perform actions using body or some other means.

If the soul reaches moksha state, then is it true that the soul is conscious? Does the soul can perform actions or is it a infinite rest state with no consciousness?

Comment: Very good question!! Here are some pointers. One is time. Time is an illusion of the Mind. In the state of Moksha there is no time. Second is actions. Actions are only performed in a body (there are three types of bodies, physical body, subtle body and causal body). During Moksha, there is no body. Here is example to understand. Everyday when we go to sleep we experience deep sleep. Are we aware of time during deep sleep? No. Are we aware of our body during deep sleep? No. But yet, when we wake up we realize it was a blissful experience. Moksha is similar except that in Moksha we become That.

Comment: In the state of Moksha there is **no conception of time**.

Comment: I think, state of Moksha is **beyond** the time!

Answer (score 5):

The state of attaining Moksha is getting merged with infinity (GOD).
For example, the identity of water is with its containing vessel (a glass of water or a cup of water). If the same glass of water is poured in ocean it becomes the ocean. The individual identity losses the moment you attain moksha.
The soul remains conscious but the level of consciousness upgrades to a much higher level that is super consciousness.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Answer (score 3):

In the state of Moksha there is **no conception of time**.

A verse in Viveka Chudamani where Adi Sankaracharya explaining about the path to moksha mentions it as below.

> जाति नीति कुल गोत्र दूरगं
>   नाम रूप गुण दोष वर्जितम् |
>   देश काल विषया तिवर्ति यद्
>   ब्रह्म तत्त्वमसि भाव यात्मनि ||२५४||
>
> Beyond caste, creed, family or lineage,
>   That which is without name and form, beyond merit and demerit,
>   That which is beyond space, time and sense-objects,
>   You are that, God himself; Meditate this within yourself. ||Verse 254||

Some attain moksha/liberation from cycle of samsara/ birth and death in one's life time that is before death who are called as jeevanuktas.

The state of bliss on union with god makes lose one's individual identity.

Just as organs/body parts are indifferent from the conception of "I" so is us who are in **union with the infinite being doesn't have the idea of time**.

Answer (score 2):

A statement in [sribhasya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Bhasya) - the final one which states na cha punaravarthate na cha punaraavarthate - ie. the person who has gone to moksha does not come back.

Though, I heard of "na cha punaravarthate na cha punaraavartha" through discourses, I was unable to quote a reference and hence took a help of an Internet search result.

Time and consciousness both have different meaning in our materialistic and physical world. Hence we can't describe how it will be in the state of moksha with our knowledge, in fact since no one has seen/realise it from here and so is the case that who has witnessed are not among us. So we have to depend on the knowledge given to selected few by the Almighty like Namazhwar or Sri Ramanujar to explain those to us.

As per their statements, there is no time at all and it is completely flexible (dilatable) to the jeevan who attained moksha.

Also it seems the question asks whether after attaining the moksha will the jeevan be in a dormant (inactive) state? In fact, it is said that the jeevan will be most actively be enjoying the state and will get most of the attributes (powers, if you may) as the paramapurusha and can do wonders in terms of our capabilities.